# Error Message Received - Subscript out of Range

Tags: vba

I've written a code and am receiving a Subscript Out of Range Error, but I've no idea why. To be honest I'm new to VBA and am applying the methods of a previous question to this instance without success, and am hoping someone might be able to help;

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "Q:\Accounts Department\JM Period End ADI\1516\Stats\Period 01\Weekly Establishment Report 2015.xlsx"
Sheets("P" & Range("C10").Value).Select
```

What I'm trying to do is open the Weekly Establishment Report file, and then jump to a tab within that file. However, this tab is subject to change, and so the reference to C10 is completing the name of the tab that I want to activate.

So, for example, open the Weekly Establishment Report and activate tab P1 Wk4, with "1 Wk4" being present in cell C10.

Thanks.

Comment: Sheets refers to the active workbook, not the one you just opened.

Comment: @VincentG If you open a workbook like this in code - it _becomes_ the active workbook

Comment: The value that's in C10 - is that cell in the workbook being opened? or in the workbook that's already open _before_ you open this new workbook?

Comment: I thought the Workbook being opened would become the active workbook, as you say.

Comment: The value in C10 is in the workbook that's already opened, in what would be the "master" workbook as it were,  where all of the work takes place I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

C10 is in the workbook that's open *before* you open the next workbook, in which case you need to do:

---

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "Q:\Accounts Department\JM Period End ADI\1516\Stats\Period 01\Weekly Establishment Report 2015.xlsx"
Sheets("P" & ws.Range("C10").Value).Select
```

---

*OR* C10 is on a different sheet than the one being activated when the workbook is opening. In which case you need to qualify the range with the correct sheet, e.g.:

---

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "Q:\Accounts Department\JM Period End ADI\1516\Stats\Period 01\Weekly Establishment Report 2015.xlsx"
Sheets("P" & Sheets(1).Range("C10").Value).Select
```

---

I'll refrain from the whole "there's no need to select anything" speech for now...

Comment: Thanks Macho Man, that's done the trick.It's all very much a learning curve at the minute but I appreciate your expertise.